# animation are not shown on jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my Struts based application on eclipse, graphics animation on jsp page are shown in preview mode (both mozilla mode and IE) like I can click to button some text animation are display(like toggle effect) but on design mode button are not give any response.
i am using jquery,css and js.

Comment: its best practice to test any web application on a real browser

Comment: Duplicate of [graphics are not shown on jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033075/graphics-are-not-shown-on-jsp)